# Using A Records with Ports

Tags: .htaccess, windows-7, dns, minecraft, ports

I have a domain which is being used as my Minecraft Server. I'm using my home server and it works fine but I don't want people to connect to my web server (:80).

So is there anyway to deny the domain from :80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to block it with Windows Firewall

http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/block-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall/